# multiple loading spinners for list of images

Tags: jquery, html, image, css, animated-gif

Trying to remove loading animations when individual images have finished loading but have run into a problem.  Loading animation is removed after first image is loaded rather than individually when specific image is loaded.

I want to have a row of images each with its own loading giff, any ideas?

This is what I have come up with so far....

```
.img-container{
float:left;
width:500px;
height:500px;}
.img-loading{
position:absolute;
background:url('loading.gif') center center no-repeat;
width:500px;
height:500px;}

<div class="img-container"><div class="img-loading"></div><img src="example.jpg"    height="500" width="500" border="0"/></div>
<div class="img-container"><div class="img-loading"></div><img src="example2.jpg" height="500" width="500" border="0"/></div>
<div class="img-container"><div class="img-loading"></div><img src="example.jpg3" height="500" width="500" border="0"/></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('img').css({'display':'none'});
$('img').bind('load', function () { $(this).fadeIn(1500);$('.img-loading').fadeOut(2000);});                
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to change the fadeOut a bit:

```
$('img').bind('load', function () { $(this).fadeIn(1500).prev().fadeOut(2000);});
```

This fades de image in and get the element that is before it and fade it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').css({'display':'none'});
    $('img').bind('load', function () { 
        $(this).fadeIn(1500);
        $(this).prev('.img-loading').fadeOut(2000);
    });                
});
```

In your code you were calling all elements with the class `.img-loading` to fadeOut when you need instead to specify the one relative to the image being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

try an `each()` function

```
$('img').each(function(){
        var container = $(this).parent();
        $(this).bind('load', function () { $(this).fadeIn(1500);$('.img-loading', container).fadeOut(2000);});
});
```

thats pretty rough may need refining, but base concept is there.